# Kotlin: How to define a variable whose type depends on the input?

Tags: kotlin, types

I have a function in Kotlin which takes a particular string as input. Depending on the input, I want to create a variable of a specific type and do some computations on it.

For example,

```
fun compute(input: String): Any{
    if(input=="2d"){
        var point: Point2D;// Points2D - x: int, y: int
        //initilize and do some computations
        return point.findDistanceFromOrigin()
    }else if(input=="2d-1"){
        var point: Point2DWithP1AsOrigin;// Point2DWithP1AsOrigin - x: int, y: int
        //initilize and do some computations
        return point.findDistanceFromOrigin()
    }else if(input=="2d-2"){
        var point: Point2DWithP2AsOrigin;
        //initilize and do some computations
        return point.findDistanceFromOrigin()
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

You can see in the above example, I want to initilize the type of point depending on the input and do computation and return.

All the if-else conditions have the same code except for the definition of the variable. How can I put all this in a single block with something like this:

```
var point: if(input=="2d) Point2D::class else if(input=="2d-1") Point2DWithP1AsOrigin::class.....
```

How can I do that?

Comment: above code should work. what is the problem?

Comment: It seems like you did it right already (although it makes sense to replace if-else with `switch` and extract `return`). The only missing part is the one that is totally specific to your project. What is the source of `x`, `y` and possibly other params?

Comment: @sidgate All the if-else conditions have the same code except for the definition of the variable. How can I put all this in a single block?

Comment: @broot All the if-else conditions have the same code except for the definition of the variable. How can I put all this in a single block?

Comment: you mean you have to extract out common code from `if-else` ? for instance `return point.findDistanceFromOrigin()` ?

Comment: @sidgate Only the variablre definition differs in all the if else blocks.

Comment: what about initialization? would be different. also, are `Point2D , Point2DWithP1AsOrigin ..` classes inheriting same parent?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
fun compute(input: String): Any{
    val point: MyPoint = when(input) {
        "2d" -> Point2D()
        "2d-1" -> Point2DWithP1AsOrigin()
        "2d-2" -> Point2DWithP2AsOrigin()
        else -> Point2D() //fallback is necessary
    }
    //initilize and do some computations
    return point.findDistanceFromOrigin()
}
```

But then it's essential that all those classes share the same interface. Because they need to have the same methods in order to do the same operations on them.
For example like this:

```
class Point2D : MyPoint {
    override fun findDistanceFromOrigin() = 5
}

class Point2DWithP1AsOrigin : MyPoint{
    override fun findDistanceFromOrigin() = 6
}

class Point2DWithP2AsOrigin : MyPoint{
    override fun findDistanceFromOrigin() = 7
}

interface MyPoint {
    fun findDistanceFromOrigin() : Int
}
```

Comment: Some of these are not `class`es, they are `typeAlias`es. How to deal in that case?

Comment: @LightYagami so how would they initialize? You say the Initialization is the same for all cases? maybe share your full code of `compute`

Answer (score 1):

You can store constructor references and then invoke required one

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val constructors = mapOf(
        "2d"   to ::Point2D,
        "2d-1" to ::Point2DWithP1AsOrigin,
        "2d-2" to ::Point2DWithP2AsOrigin,
    )

    val type = "2d-2"
    val constructor = constructors[type] ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("$type not supported")
    val point = constructor()

    println(point::class)
}
```

Output

```
class Point2DWithP2AsOrigin
```